# How can I rotate and paste image with alpha channel using vImage in ios?

Tags: c++, ios, affinetransform, accelerate-framework, vimage

I have a large image A and another image B which has an alpha channel that I would like to paste into A. I want to apply an affine transform to B before I stick it on to A. What are the steps to doing this in c++ using vImage in iOS?

Comment: I regret there is a lot of missing detail here.  Are the images CGImageRefs? vImage_Buffers? JPEGs? UIImages? How many channels are in B. Do you intend to overwrite the alpha already in A or blend it in?  Is A premultiplied? It may be that the simplest answer if you are unfamiliar with low level graphics details is to prepare a CGImageMask and attach it to the CGImageRef.

Comment: vInage_buffers, alpha exists in both images, premultiplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you were able to get any of the answers posted here to work; there are just not enough specifics in them to help someone who had a question like this to begin with.

Here's your working answer:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)copyRenderedPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer {

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

unsigned char *base = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress( pixelBuffer );
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth( pixelBuffer );
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight( pixelBuffer );
size_t stride = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow( pixelBuffer );
//size_t extendedWidth = stride / sizeof( uint32_t ); // each pixel is 4 bytes/32 bits
vImage_Buffer _img = {
    .data = base,
    .height = height,
    .width = width,
    .rowBytes = stride
};

size_t pixelBufferSize = (stride  * height) / sizeof(uint8_t);
void* gBuffer = malloc(pixelBufferSize);
vImage_Buffer _dstG = {
    .data = gBuffer,
    .height = height / sizeof(uint8_t),
    .width = width / sizeof(uint8_t),
    .rowBytes = stride / sizeof(uint8_t)
};

vImage_Error err;

const uint8_t map[4] = { 3, 2, 1, 0 };
err = vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(&_img, &_img, map, kvImageNoFlags);
if (err != kvImageNoError)
    NSLog(@"Error: %ld", err);

err = vImageExtractChannel_ARGB8888(&_img, &_dstG, 2, kvImageNoError);
if (err != kvImageNoError)
    NSLog(@"Error: %ld", err);

err = vImageEqualization_Planar8(&_dstG, &_dstG, kvImageNoError);
if (err != kvImageNoError)
    NSLog(@"Error: %ld", err);

err = vImageContrastStretch_Planar8( &_dstG, &_dstG, kvImageNoError );
if (err != kvImageNoError)
    NSLog(@"Error: %ld", err);

err = vImageOverwriteChannels_ARGB8888(&_dstG, &_img, &_img, 0x2, kvImageNoError);
if (err != kvImageNoError)
    NSLog(@"Error: %ld", err);

err = vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(&_img, &_img, map, kvImageNoFlags);
if (err != kvImageNoError)
    NSLog(@"Error: %ld", err);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

free(gBuffer);

return (CVPixelBufferRef)CFRetain( pixelBuffer );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 8-bits per component, 4 channel data:

1. Unpremultiply A -- vImageUnpremultiplyData_ARGB8888
2. extract alpha channel from B -- vImageExtractChannel_ARGB8888
3. transform B -- vImageAffineWarp_Planar8
4. extract alpha channel from A -- vImageExtractChannel_ARGB8888
5. multiply the two alpha channels together -- vImagePremultiplyData_Planar8
6. write the result into A -- vImageOverwriteChannels_ARGB8888
7. premultiply A -- vImagePremultiplyData_ARGB8888

If you really wanted to replace the alpha of A with B rather than composite them together, skip steps 4 and 5.

The whole thing will run quite a bit faster if you do all 7 steps on one scanline, before moving on to the next scanline.  kvImageDoNotTile and dispatch_apply() can be used to multithread it fairly simply.

> On premultiplication: You may have a choice as to whether the images
>   are premultiplied or not. The performance benefits for compositing of
>   premultiplied images is usually overstated. It is only marginally more
>   work to composite a non-premultiplied image into a premultiplied
>   surface than it is to composite a premultiplied one. Premultiplication causes problems for  most image filters, resulting
>   in a bunch of work unpremultiplying and premultiplying again. It also
>   causes some precision loss. As you can see above, if the images are
>   not premultiplied, then the operations you want to do become much
>   simpler. It could be a simple as just steps 2 and 6, or a single pass
>   with vImageSelectChannels_ARGB8888 / vImagePermuteChannelsWithMaskedInsert_ARGB8888().